# wordpress permalinks & htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

i have  a client who have its wordpress site in behind cakephp site,

and his blog permalinks are not working, we want to include the site domain and this subdomain of wordpress installation as one link,

need help or suggestions for htaccess

the cakephp site and wordpress are working line this

www.domain.com/knowledge-base/

here domain.com is haivng cake php and /knowledge-base is wordpress site,
now permalinks in htaccess are linke that,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /legal-knowledge-base/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /legal-knowledge-base/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

this htaccss is in wordpress site,

Answer (score 0):

WordPress should be able to create the htaccess in the subdirectory automatically.

If in the parent directory, you have a htaccess that's trying to route EVERYTHING to the CakePHP install, that could be the problem.

When you go to domain.com/legal-knowledge-base/testing does it show a WordPress error, or an error from the CakePHP application?

If the later, then you need to sort out your root directory htaccess rules